# Create Dynamic Dataframe pySpark

Tags: pyspark

Is it possible to create DataFrame dynamically.

Example want to create list of Dates and its Day in two columns for given date range?

```
Input:- 03-01-2018 - 03-31-2018

03-01-2018 THU
03-02-2018 FRI

.......

03-31-2018 SAT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python for that and then export to spark :

```python
import datetime
start = datetime.date(2018,3,1)
end = datetime.date(2018,3,31)

date_list = []
for i in range((end - start).days+1):
    date_list.append(start+datetime.timedelta(days=i))

sc.parallelize(date_list).take(2)
[datetime.date(2018, 3, 1), datetime.date(2018, 3, 2)]
sc.parallelize(date_list).count()
31
```

In the case your date range is within a dataframe, you have to create an UDF which takes as args the 2 dates and return an array of dates, then you explode it.

Comment: Yes I prefer explode option., But possible to apply explode on empty data frame? I have to define DataFrame and apply explode?

Comment: @syv your dataframe is not empty. Your starting point is the dataframe with the start/end columns

Comment: Can I take start/end as parameters when i submit the script into Spark I'll supply them? Anyways like that.

Comment: @syv if they are parameters, you use the method i wrote.The explode works only with data from dataframe.

Comment: OK Thank you !!